# How do I send calls from numbers not in contacts to voicemail?

Tags: iphone, contacts, voicemail, caller-id

I'd like to send all of the calls that I receive from numbers that are not in my contacts to voicemail.

Is this possible on ios10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible with the Phone app included in iOS 10 (nor with any earlier version).